# Printing text on the webpage using PHP/AJAX/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following simple Form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="button" value="Generate Numbers" onclick="on_callPhp1()"/>
</form>
```

And this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function on_callPhp()
{
    var result = "<?php php_func1();?>";
    alert(result);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

and this PHP Script

```
function php_func1()
{
    echo "Hello PHP";
}
?>
```

The above works perfectly, and whenever I press the button, I can see the Alert of the PHP.
However, I do not want the alert to be seen, instead, I want the `Hello PHP` text be written on the page. For that I tried, to remove the `alert(result);` and instead put `echo (result);` but it did not work and nothing shows.

I want the text to appear in the `body` of the page.

Mainly, I will be putting a for loop and generate random numbers inside `php_func1()` and I want them to appear under the buttons. e

Any ideas?

Comment: But where do you want message to appear in the page? e.g, `$('body').append(result);` would append it to the body  EDIT: to append it 'under' the button: `$(this).after(result);`

Comment: PHP is Serverside and will be run once when the page is loaded. Javascript is Clientside, so to add, remove, change and so on, when the page is loaded you need to use javascript

Comment: use ajax or $.post to call php function then console response it will print php

Comment: @A.Wolff in the body. check updated Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're immediately looking to do is as simple as the following I suppose:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="button" value="Generate Numbers" onclick="on_callPhp()"/>
</form>
<div id="phptext"></div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function on_callPhp()
  {
      var result = "<?php php_func1();?>";

      document.getElementById('phptext').innerHTML = result;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.